# How to mock Routes and constants in vue3 component test case using vitest

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

Below is my vue3 component getting issues in writing test cases with vitest and @vue/test-utils

```
    <template>
      <link-component
        v-tooltip="'My tooltip'"
        :to="{ name: ROUTES.myRoute, query: { me: 'pk'} }"
      />
    </template>
    <script setup>
    import ROUTES from '@/services/routes';
    </script>
```

value of ROUTES just an object here {myRoute:"myRoute"}
link-component is simply

```
  <template>
    <router-link
      :to="to"
      class="link"
    >
      <button />
    </router-link>
  </template>
```

Now i tried to mock this

```
vi.mock('@/services/routes', () => ({
  myRoute: 'my-path',
}));
```

I am getting below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myRoute')
 ❯ Proxy._sfc_render MyComponent.vue:36:27
     34|     <link-component
     35|      v-tooltip="'My tooltip'"
     36|       :to="{ name: ROUTES.myRoute, query: { me: 'pk'} }"
       |                           ^
     37|     />
     38|   </div>
```

What could be problem? What am i missing here? how I can solve this.